# Is there Notion API to fetch all the pages ID of a user using userId or email?

Tags: notion-api, notion

I am using notion OAuth2 access token to get the list of pages that has access for a user's id / or this access token.
Is there any apis or other way to achive this senario
Currently is am using https://api.notion.com/v1/oauth/token api to create a access token
and i get a response like

{
access_token: 'secret_Pkjfd43UIuIUiuwefhuwefhujinIijsfdvnx',
token_type: 'bearer',
bot_id: '2jndf8b-8kja2-48e2-a3d1-9jefknm8nad15965',
workspace_name: 'SagaSense-logesh-local',
workspace_icon: null,
workspace_id: '3kjad8beca-1471-4aed-bc74-k8kjhd4176de1',
owner: {
type: 'user',
user: {
object: 'user',
id: '246jkwdf98d-aa4c-4fb7-980e-knjdf740e5200',
name: 'Logesh Kumar',
avatar_url: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/HFYEFNEFHBJHBEFXj8U6tNsz8bKI9_PxkUVPZn=s100',
type: 'person',
person: [Object]
}
},
duplicated_template_id: null,
request_id: '1a3ca1f9-badd-411a-b580-adf23cdsg060a68'
}